# C# Form - transparent applications WebView2 unclickable

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, webview2

When I create transparent applications with WebView2 c# form,
It is not possible to click on visible elements.

When I click, it clicks on the window behind.
I don't have the problem with WebBrowser

Do you have a solution ?

Thank you

```
            // 
            // webView21
            // 
            this.webView21.CreationProperties = null;
            this.webView21.DefaultBackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.webView21.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(462, 12);
            this.webView21.Name = "webView21";
            this.webView21.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(337, 429);
            this.webView21.Source = new System.Uri("https://***", System.UriKind.Absolute);
            this.webView21.TabIndex = 2;
            this.webView21.ZoomFactor = 1D;

            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.webBrowser1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.webView21);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.webView21)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

[image]

Comment: Try a non-named color for transpkeycolor..

Comment: Please give me an example

Comment: Try this: ` Color col = Color.FromArgb(1,2,3,4); this.BackColor= col; this.TransparencyKey = col; `

Comment: I have an error :( 
"System.ArgumentException: 'The control does not support transparent background colors.'"

Comment: Well, Color.FromArgb(1,2,3,4) should not be transparent, but maybe Color.FromArgb(123,2,3,4) is accepted. If not there must be some other reason..

Comment: I experience the the same problem, I have transparent window (with WS_EX_LAYERED), I draw header and it works fine (i.e. clickable) but web view is not clickable even though it is visible.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change the `TransparencyKey` to `Color.Red`, and the webview will be clickable.

Example:

```cs
this.BackColor = Color.Red;
this.TransparencyKey = Color.Red;
```

But I'm still looking for a way to not lose focus on the overlay's target window when I click on the webview content.